# Angular Module 'cordovaHTTP' is not available

Tags: angularjs, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I am running Ionic and trying to use cordovaHTTP for SSL pinning. I followed the instructions on the the [github](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) but I get the error that the module isn't there.

My index.html

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

My app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'cordovaHTTP'])
```

In services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.service('MyService', function(cordovaHTTP) {

    cordovaHTTP.enableSSLPinning(true, function() {
        console.log('successful ssl pin');

        cordovaHTTP.useBasicAuth("user", "pass", function() {
            console.log('successful basic auth!');

            cordovaHTTP.get(url, function(response) {
                console.log(response.status);
            }, function(response) {
                console.error(response.error);
            });
        }, function() {
            console.log('error basic auth');
        });     
    }, function(){
        console.log('error ssl pin');
    });
});
```

This results in the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cordovaHTTP due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'cordovaHTTP' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I have tried messing with this countless times but no dice. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just load `app.js` at last

Comment: Nothing changed :/ Wouldn't think it would either because that would break the controller and service anyway.

Comment: You should use one module instance for a single application. You may be getting this error due to initilization of two modules.

Comment: @Vineet, so just do var app = angular.module('starter') then do app.service() ?

Comment: Could it be that because cordova.js 404's during development that the Cordova plugin fails as well?

Comment: @PizzaPleb have you solved it?

Comment: @Shay, unfortunately I did not. I couldn't tell if it needed to be imported/required in more places throughout the project or if the app had to be built/deployed first (for cordova to start working).

Comment: Thanks anyway, that plugin was badly planned imo... angular code inside the plugins directory... There is a relatively new plugin that does ssl pinning that i'm using, maybe it'll help you out in the future! https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Cool, thanks! I agree, the plugin did not seem very robust.

Comment: @Shay can you explain how to define SSLCertificateChecker plugin in angular module ionic, because after try to install that plugin, I got module not available too ?

Comment: @Redturbo The SSLCertificateChecker as I remember does not use the angular module dependency, it's a pure javascript library working on the global window.plugins object, used by many other cordova plugins...

Comment: @Shay but why when I try call window.plugins.sslCertificateChecker.check, this error message appear : "Cannot read property 'sslCertificateChecker' of undefined" ?

Comment: @Redturbo First check if the plugin is installed properly, secondly this plugin as some other cordova plugins only works in the **device**, it will not work on the browser, therefore test it on the device using the github's instructions on how to use it, and i'm sure you'll be successful ^^

Comment: @Shay Okay thanks, now it worked, I just forget to add Content-Security-Policy in index.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you're initializing your module multiple times. In angular `factories / services` are singleton. Your code look like something this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'MyService', 'cordovaHTTP']) //setters for a module
```

Please make sure you're injecting right service or factory name. You should change your service declaration way too, like below

```
angular.module('starter') //Don't use [] it is only getter of above initialized module

.service('MyService', function(cordovaHTTP){ 
      //Code
});
```

Also please don't forget to load `app.js` at last. Hope it may help you.

Comment: Tried all of this. Still nothing. Also, putting app.js at the bottom throws errors because the main (starter) module in app.js that the service uses hasn't been defined yet. Thanks for helping, though. I feel like it's something small that I'm missing.

Comment: what is `ionic` in module init ?

Comment: I'm guessing the angular methods used in the mobile UI framework, Ionic, that I'm using. Disabling it didn't do anything.

Comment: angular methods ?? Will you please elaborate it for me ?

Comment: Perhaps method isn't the right word. For instance: ionic.Platform.isFullScreen = true;

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [github issues](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP/issues/22).

1. Make sure that you load the angular js files after cordova js files in `index.html`.

Here's my index.html:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

2. Is `angular` defined?

> cordova-HTTP will only instantiate the cordovaHTTP module if angular is defined otherwise it will fall back to window.cordovaHTTP.

You could use this this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  console.log(window.cordovaHTTP);
  console.log(window.CordovaHttpPlugin);  // For some version it's instantiated in this name if angular is not defined.
}, false);
```

3. Manually bootstrap your AngularJS app instead of using the `ng-app` attribute.

Code:

```
<script>
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
          console.log(window.cordovaHTTP);
          console.log(window.CordovaHttpPlugin);  // For some version it's instantiated in this name if angular is not defined.
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyAppName']);
      }, false);
  });
</script>
```

4. When using it in your controller or service, do not need to add the `$`.

Just use it like this:

```
angular.module('MyAppName.services', [])
.service('MyService', ['cordovaHTTP', function(cordovaHTTP){
    // Your codes are here.
}]);
```